# Python random random function providing correct output for an integer with specific length as 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, random

Sometimes when I try to run the below line in my code, it is provides a 2 digit integer.
Any changes that I need to make in the below line for it show me the correct length integers all the time.

random_int = random.randrange(0,999,3)

Comment: Just format the value wherever you're outputting it.

Comment: `random.randrange(100,1000)`?

Comment: read the documentation for randrange... the 3rd argument isn't what you think it is - and you don't need to tell it how many digits you want you just need to specify the number to be between 100 and 1000